# Too many redirects to MicrosoftIdentity/Account/AccessDenied

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, blazor, .net-8.0, microsoft-identity-platform

I have a blazor server app with AAD login. I want to restrict access only to specific users (based on user roles).

program.cs

```
builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection(AppConsts.Config.AzureAdSectionKey))

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});

builder.Services
    .AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

//app.MapRazorPages(); when commented I get endless redirection to MicrosoftIdentity/Account/AccessDenied?ReturnUrl=%2FMicrosoftIdentity%2FAccount%2FAccessDenied%3FReturnUrl%
app.MapControllers();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode()
    .RequireAuthorization();
```

I restrict access to my app using ClaimsTransformation so that it cannot be overriden in AuthorizationPolicy

```
public class ClaimsTransformation : IClaimsTransformation
{

    public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        if (!IsUserAllowed(principal))
        {
            var emptyClaimIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity();
            emptyClaimIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, principal.Identity?.Name ?? "anonym"));
            return new ClaimsPrincipal(emptyClaimIdentity);
        }
        return principal;    
    }
}
```

Now I'm getting endless redirects to MicrosoftIdentity/Account/AccessDenied.
However when I add razor pages, I get proper "Access denied" page response.

1. Why is the AccessDenied page being redirected at all?
2. Is MicrosoftIdentityUI package dependent on razor pages? I thought they switched to controllers

[image]